# Non-uniform heat flux on a cube face defined by a matrix

Tags: matlab, heatmap, pde

I am trying to model the heating effects of a patterned beam (e.g. a multimode laser spot) on a large rectangular slab of material.
I can define a uniform heat flux and emissivity on the front face but I would like to be able to apply the heat flux as a 2D array of flux values (basically projecting the radiometric image). I know that this non-uniform heat flux needs to be defined as a @function handle but I just can't get it to work (because of "incompatible array sizes"). Do I need to make the heat flux map align with the mesh nodes?

```
% Create the PDE model
model = createpde("thermal","transient");
% Define a single cube using multi cube command
geo = multicuboid(1,1,1);
% Include the geometry in the model
model.Geometry = geo;
% Plot the geometry with face labels
pdegplot(model,"faceLabels","on")
% Generate mesh
generateMesh(model);
% Display the mesh (using default triangle size)
pdemesh(model);
% Set the thermal properties
thermalProperties(model,"ThermalConductivity",0.435, "MassDensity",1.450, "SpecificHeat",1109);
% Define this constant
model.StefanBoltzmannConstant = 5.670373E-8;
% CREATE THIS FUNCTION FOR THE NEXT STEP (A simple pattern for testing)
%function Qflux = externalHeatFluxI(region,~)
%Qflux = zeros(100);
%Qflux(:, 45:55) = 30;
%Qflux = Qflux+10;
%end
% Apply spatially varying heat flux to front face
X = zeros(100);
X = X+10;
region.x = X;
region.y = X;
region.z = X;
thermalBC(model,"Face",6, "HeatFlux",@externalHeatFluxI, "Vectorized","on")
% Set initial temperature
thermalIC(model,16);
% Specify Solution Times
tlist = 0:1:1000;
% Calculate Solution
thermalresults = solve(model,tlist);
% Plot Temperature Distribution
pdeplot3D(thermalresults.Mesh(:,end),ColorMapData=thermalresults.Temperature(:,end));
```

I want to see my 2D array of irradiance (W/m^2) values appear as a heating effect on the face of the cube and trace what this does to the cube face temperature over time.